# Definindo uma estrutura de arvore em ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em ruby on rails, e estou travado em uma questão.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu preciso criar uma arvore, e então criar meu objeto 'no' e gostaria que ele tivesse um pai do tipo 'no' e uma lista de filhos do tipo 'no'. tentei a seguinte abordagem:

```
    class No< ApplicationRecord
            belongs_to :arvore # Objeto pai
            belongs_to :pai, class_name: "No", primary_key: "pai_id" #Atributo do pai
    has_many :filhos, class_name: "No" ,foreign_key: "filho_id" # Lista de filhos
    end
```

mas não consegui definir o pai nem adicionar os filhos.
Vocês poderiam me dar uma dica do que fazer?

Comment: Você pode mostrar a estrutura da tabela "nos"?

Comment: Se puder incluir as estruturas e models para a classe `arvore` também ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que você pode fazer facilmente usando a gem [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que a tabela **nos** possua uma chave para o pai (pai_id),
defina os relacionamentos da seguinte maneira:

```
class No < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pai, class_name: "No"
  has_many :filhos, class_name: "No", foreign_key: :pai_id
end
```

E o modelo árvore ter a referência do nó raiz (ter a coluna raiz_id ou no_id)

```
class Arvore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :raiz, primary_key: :no_id
end
```

Assim voce pode criar:

```
raiz = No.new
filho1 = No.new(pai: raiz)
filho2 = No.new(pai: raiz)
filho_segundo_nivel = No.new(pai: filho1)

arvore = Arvore.new(raiz: raiz)
```